# SQL - flagging data based on certain values

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have an area for uploading CSV files which are exploded into my DB table called 'import'. This holds the whole CSV file for now.

I have the database table displaying on the front end of the website in a JQuery datatable. All of this works perfectly. However, I now need to use the database and this table to show some QA properties.

Within this CSV file there are 8 or 9 columns that depend on values in preceding columns. My supervisor wants the datatable on the front end to display those dependent values in red, or with some type of flag/notice, if there's an issue with those preceding columns. Some of these columns contain text and some contain numbers, so I imaging I'll have to create each statement slightly differently but I'm trying to find a universal way to do this where I can factor in the different values.

For example, if `lowSideMIUNumArriv` and `lowSideMIUNumDepart` are different numbers, the `miu` column value should say YES to show that there was a change. If the numbers in those columns are the same, `miu` should say NO. Someone helped me with a trigger earlier that would change the value but I need a way to flag it so that it can be seen and then edited within the front end datatable.

Here's one way of explaining the issue:

```
First    SECOND    THIRD
a        b         c
a        b         d
```

So the first line is right and the second is wrong, because 'a' and 'b' should result in 'c' in the third column. So on my front end datatable, I want to see the first line as normal but the third line with a flag on 'd'. Possibly by highlighing in red or something like that.

For a SQL novice, is there a fairly simple way of implementing this?

Comment: So you have a column that flags the record? Just make the front end change the color for the records with flags = true. If you have them identified in SQL you can't really do much *more* in SQL. You can't change the color from the database.

Comment: @JacobH oh, i know I can't change the color from the database, but I don't have a flag column necessarily either. This is where I'm confused on what to do. The CSV is populated from a handheld and might have errors, so in the table there will be a number for the 2 columns in my above example and the 'miu' column will either have Yes or No and if the answer doesn't match with the condition of those two numbers, it needs to be flagged.

Comment: could I make a flags table that would create a true or false based off of each set of QA?

Comment: I don't think it would even need to be a separate table. You could have the flags on the same row in the table in another column.

Comment: @JacobH sorry, last question: I'm updating my question with a screenshot of the current front end table. It displays exactly what's coming from the CSV, so it has one column for every column in the CSV and database table. Could I have the SQL statement check the conditions and then create a flag in another column for the 'miu' value, and then on the front end check 'miuFlag' to either have TRUE = green or FALSE = red? So that I wouldn't have to display the flags on the front end but just use them to dictate the color?